# Creality Ender 3 v2 1st layer too high off bed

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

On my Creality Ender 3 v2, I have performed bed levelling and am fairly confident that the nozzle height is correct - a piece of paper under the nozzle can be pulled out with a gentle tug. For some reason, the first layer that prints always has the nozzle too far off the bed and so it's not adhering correctly.

I'm not sure if I've missed something with bed levelling, or if there is some other setting I need to tweak.

FYI I'm printing with a 0.8 mm diameter nozzle with 0.5 mm layer height and 0.45 mm initial layer height. When I look at the printer in action, the first pass looks like the nozzle is about 1 mm off the bed.

Comment: Are you using a BL/CR Touch?

Comment: No I don’t think so. That’s the auto-levelling thing, right?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried lowering the Z Limit Switch bracket?

Comment: No, I did see some article mentioning to make sure it’s straight, but not tried to lower it yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nozzle not level and first print failed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/nozzle-not-level-and-first-print-failed)

Comment: Can you add a photo and a link to your G-code to see if there is something wrong in the start G-code? Without much more information, this could be closed referring to the previously mentioned topic as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there were two things wrong here:

1. I was not levelling the bed correctly - I was manually moving the z-axis down to the lower limit - which can be slightly different to the printer lowering until the limit switch activates (Menu > Prepare > Auto home).
2. Looking at the suggested answer [Nozzle not level and first print failed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/nozzle-not-level-and-first-print-failed) I did check the position of my z-axis limit switch and it was pushed all the way downwards. I decided to try filing a bit off the notch which rests on the base rails so that the z-limit would be hit a bit lower.

Comment: Is this an answer that solves your issue, or actually an update to the question? If the latter, then please edit your question and add it there. If the former, then please mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for offsets to the home positions. M206 will show home offsets. If you have automated bed levelling with probing there is another offset to view with M851. Depending on firmware versions you might have to run M503 to show all the offsets.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you explain how I use those G-codes to get the offsets?